# How can I save my Windows 10 license across a drive replacement?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssd, license, reinstall

I have a Windows 10 Pro installed on a desktop PC with a 128GB SSD and a 1 TB HDD. Windows is installed on the SSD, and it is a digital license (probably upgraded from Win7). The HDD started failing so I bought a new 512GB SSD to replace it, but haven't installed it yet.

I also want to use a Linux distro on this PC exclusively for a while, but I want to re-install Windows later. I expect the cleanest way to go about this is to format the old 128 GB SSD and install the Linux on it.

I know that I should be able to re-install the Windows later, and activate it with my linked MS account, as long as the hardware is unchanged. What I'm worried about, is the new 512 GB SSD invalidating the activation.

Dual-boot should theoretically be possible, but I want to know if there is a way to save the Windows license for later even in the case of a complete wipe.

Comment: A single drive replacement won't invalidate the activation.

Comment: Thank you @Mokubai! I hoped so. Do you know where I can find what the exact criteria are for matching the hardware?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/reactivating-windows-after-a-hardware-change-2c0e962a-f04c-145b-6ead-fb3fc72b6665

Comment: Thank you again @Mokubai ! While that support page does not specify the criteria for what counts as a "significant hardware change", it tells me how I can reactivate through the linked account event if the hardware change is significant. That looks good enough!

Comment: @John I'd think so too, but I haven't found a specific answer, only speculation. Although, with the comment above, seems like it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft keeps the details of digital entitlement a secret,
so full details do not exist.

The Microsoft article
[Activate Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/activate-windows-c39005d4-95ee-b91e-b399-2820fda32227)
has this text:

> **Reactivating Windows 10 after a hardware change**
>
> When you make a significant hardware change to your device, such as
> replacing the motherboard, Windows 10 might no longer be activated.

This suggests that the only single major hardware change
that can invalidate the digital entitlement of a computer
is the replacement of the motherboard.

As we don't know the details of the algorithm, I can't say
which accumulation of less-major changes can have the same
effect.

However, I can say from experience that changing the disk
is not enough to invalidate the entitlement.